# Polymorphism in C++ when parsing user input

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I am working on an application that parses user input (command) and tries to process the command. There are various types of command. So I created one Base class, which all commands will inherit from. Now I am trying to figure out how to correctly process the command. What I would like to do is to create an instance of the Base class and then somehow recast it to the correct descendant. Ideally, this would be done at the level of the command classes, eg Base, Der1, Der2, no in main function as in example.

main.cpp

```
#include "class1.hpp"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
Base com("some input");
com.process(); //based on the input I want to distinguish which of the derived classes should be used   
}
```

class1.hpp

```
#include <iostream>


class Base {
std::string input;
public:
 Base(std::string input) {
    this->input = input;
}
 virtual void process(){}
};

class Der1 {
public:
 Der1(std::string input);
 void process() {
    std::cout << "Der1 process" << std::endl;
 }
};

class Der2 {
public:
 Der2(std::string input);
 void process() {
    std::cout << "Der2 process" << std::endl;
 }
};
```

Is this correct attitude when parsing user input? Or maybe is there some different approach that I might try? I prefer to use polymorphism as part of learning c++.
Thank you for any answer.

Comment: Seems like you should have a function that can infer type type from the input and construct class based on that.  Maybe start with just a `switch`?

Comment: You are probably looking for a factory. It takes the string input, parse it and produces an object of the associated class. The hard thing is the parsing. In its simplest form you just have to compare the input string against the commands names. If you also have switches, things get harder. `Base* make_command( const char* input ) {…`.

Comment: I have the parsing done already, just didnt post it to make the question easier. So I would make this function make_command, and based on the input I would create either object of type Der1 or Der2 and return pointer to it?

Comment: @TobyV. Yes, you should create an object derived from `Base`

Comment: Note that dynamic polymorphism does only work through pointer to base class. So anywhere you want to use dynamic polymorphism you manage object life-time and virtual destruction or use something that manages it (like smart pointer),

Comment: "create an instance of the Base class and then somehow recast it to the correct descendant" is precisely how inheritance does NOT work in C++.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this correct attitude when parsing user input?

In C++, we usually try to keep the full type instead of erasing it to a base class: then we need no virtual dispatch, can fully use templates/overloads etc.

> Or maybe is there some different approach that I might try?

Definitely: try to use static polymorphism instead. I think in your example something like this would be enough:

```
struct Der1 {
    Der1(std::string_view); // TODO
    auto process() { return "processed by Der1"sv; }
};

struct Der2 {
    Der2(std::string_view); // TODO
    auto process() { return "processed by Der2"sv; }
};

auto process(std::string_view input) {
    switch (input.at(0)) { // I don't know how you actually want to choose DerN
        case '1': return Der1{input}.process();
        case '2': return Der2{input}.process();
        default: throw std::runtime_error{"couldn't decide how to process"};
    }
}

int main() { std::cout << process("1some input") << '\n'; }
```

Comment: In C++ we use the right tool for the job. If the right tool for the job is inheritance based dynamic polymorphism with virtual dispatch, we use it.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I mean - it is used a lot more often than needed. When you *actually* need dynamic polymorphism, you surely go for it.